# Problems making a fitnesse test

Tags: java, sql, testing, fitnesse

I´m trying to do this test on fitnesse, but actually it inserts only the first one (|Execute|INSERT INTO restdb.labels (id, label_name) VALUES (1, "label_test1")|)
Apparently the other are ignored... I´ve debugged it using eclipse and I´m checking everything on HEIDSQL.

```
!2 Add Credit to account

!3 Insert the entities
|Execute|INSERT INTO restdb.labels (id, label_name) VALUES (1, "label_test1")|

|Execute|INSERT INTO restdb.labels (id, label_name) VALUES (2, "label_test2")|

|Execute|INSERT INTO service_labels (id_service, id_label) VALUES (1,1)|

|Execute|INSERT INTO service_labels (id_service, id_label) VALUES (1,2)|

|Execute|INSERT INTO service_labels (id_service, id_label) VALUES (2,2)|

!|DatabaseEnvironment|

|Commit|

!4 Add the credits
!|smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture|http://${REST_HOST}:${REST_PORT}${REST_ENDPOINT}|
|setHeader|!- Content-Type : application/json
X-BT-Ribbit-SP-AppId : -!${DEFAULT_APP}!-
X-BT-Ribbit-SP-UserId : -!${DEFAULT_GUID}|
|setBody||
|DELETE|/users/test/1|200|||
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody said anything but I´ll post the solution I´ve found anyway !!

I´ve added a black line between each command...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the fixture you might need to keep the commands in one table, i.e., without empty lines between rows. At least some other wikis I've seen interpret it as a new table when you have an empty line between rows.